# why function ls { ls; } hangs in there?

Tags: bash, shell

The following shell function definition hangs on there in bash console (RHEL/Ubuntu) in Cygwin it just quits the terminal when it is invoked.

```
$ function ls { ls; }
$ ls
```

Any reason why this behavior is?

Comment: because it recursively calls itself to infinity?

Comment: What is purpose of this function?

Comment: Once you define a function named `ls` your shell won't search the path and find `/bin/ls`. Did you (for some reason) want `function ls { /bin/ls; }`? And why?

Comment: Yes [Elliott Frisch](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch), I intented to call **/bin/ls** inside my function. So I inferred that shell function overrides or having precedence over built-ins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your defined `ls` command is recursively calling *itself* rather than the *previous* `ls` command.

If you want to call the actual `ls` from your redefined one, you can simply use `which` to get the full path name, such as redefining `ls` to give you the long format:

```
function ls { $(which ls) -l; }
```

That's effectively the same as:

```
function ls { /bin/ls -l; }
```

which won't give you the problems your solution has with recursion.

Another option is to use

```
function ls { command ls -l; }
```

`command` will suppress shell function lookup and only allow for built-ins or programs on the path.

---

Builtins (like `cd`) are handled slightly differently to programs since they aren't actually located on the file system. In that case, you can use `builtin`, rather then `which`, to call the built-in version.

---

If you want to define a function in terms of something that may *already* be a function, that's a bit trickier. You can use `declare -f` to get the current definition, then manipulate that to create a *new* definition.

An example of this (though contrived) follows. Let's say you declare a function to show all text files:

```
pax> showtxt()
...> {
...>    ls *.txt
...> }
```

and you now want to give it a pretty heading. Using `declare -f showtxt`, you can see it's definition:

```
pax> declare -f showtxt
showtxt () 
{ 
    ls *.txt
}
```

Running that may result in the following output:

```
pax> showtxt
passwords.txt p0rnsites.txt results.txt
```

Now say you wanted to *change* it to give it a heading. You can capture the output of `declare -f` and modify it to make a script which will redefine the function thus:

```
pax> declare -f showtxt | awk '$1=="ls"{print "echo Text files:"}{print}' >tmp.sh
pax> cat tmp.sh
showtxt () 
{ 
echo Text files:
    ls *.txt
}
```

You can see that you now have a modified function definition which, when run, will replace the function:

```
pax> . ./tmp.sh
pax> declare -f showtxt
showtxt () 
{ 
    echo Text files:;
    ls *.txt
}
```

And, when you run the new function, it's behaviour has changed:

```
pax> showtxt
Text files:
passwords.txt p0rnsites.txt results.txt
```

Now that contrived example isn't *that* useful since you probably could have typed in in yourself. Where this comes in handy is when the original function is more complex or the changes you want to make to it are many and varied.

Comment: `which` is not (at least in bash) a built-in command, and it can be a little expensive to run (probably not noticeably so). You can use the `command` built-in to bypass any shell function: `function ls { command ls -l; }`

Comment: Didn't know about that one, Keith. Added to the answer for completeness. Ta.

Comment: Nice explanation [paxdiablo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo), but could not understand your last statement, that is, "`If you want to define a function in terms of something that may already be a function, that's a bit trickier. You can use declare -f to get the current definition, then manipulate that to create a new definition`" Could you please provide an example to illustrate this clearly?

Comment: @Ibrahim, I've added some (hopefully) clarifying extra stuff. You'd generally only need it for complex stuff but the bottom line is that `declare` can give you the function in a form you can modify to change said function.

Comment: Thank you [paxdiablo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) for enlightening !!

Answer (score 1):

You named your function `ls`. Now, this overrides any other function(s) which were named `ls` before. So, as a result, your function calls itself recursively infinitely...

The best idea is to use unique names for your functions, i.e., this works fine:

```
function myls { ls; }
```